# mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

There is the function `get_show_listing` that queries a MySQL database and filters the set based on the passed argument (or lack of). Upon unit testing for the case of an argument being passed, the following error is being raised. I'm looking to understand what is causing this error; especially with whatever argument is passed into the function.

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Action' in 'where clause'
```

```
def db_connect(func):
    def wrapper_db_connect(*args, **kwargs):
        with mysql.connector.connect(**credentials) as db_connection:
            cursor = db_connection.cursor(dictionary=True)
            return func(cursor, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper_db_connect

@db_connect
def get_show_listing(cursor, genre=None):
    if not genre:
        cursor.execute("""
            SELECT t.title, t.view_rating, YEAR(t.release_date), t.score, t.votes, g.name
            FROM tvshow AS t LEFT JOIN show_genre as s
            ON t.title = s.tvshow_title RIGHT JOIN genre as g
            ON s.genre_name = g.name ORDER BY votes DESC LIMIT 5;
        """)
    else:
        cursor.execute(f"""
            SELECT t.title, t.view_rating, YEAR(t.release_date), t.score, t.votes, g.name
            FROM tvshow AS t LEFT JOIN show_genre as s
            ON t.title = s.tvshow_title RIGHT JOIN genre as g
            ON s.genre_name = g.name WHERE g.name = {genre}
            ORDER BY votes DESC LIMIT 5;
        """)
    return cursor.fetchall()
```

```
class TestShowListing(unittest.TestCase):


    @patch.dict('main.credentials', test_db_config)
    def test_db_query_show_listing_with_genre(self):
        shows = get_show_listing(genre="Action")
        self.assertTrue(all(
            shows[i]['votes'] > shows[i + 1]['votes'] and show[i]['votes']
            for i in range(len(shows) - 1)
        ))
```

```
genre_table = """
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS genre (
        name VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY
    );
"""

show_table = """
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tvshow (
        title VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        view_rating VARCHAR(8),
        release_date DATE,
        summary TEXT,
        score DECIMAL(2, 1),
        votes INT,
        PRIMARY KEY(title)
    );
"""

show_genre_table = """
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS show_genre (
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        genre_name VARCHAR(20) NULL,
        tvshow_title VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (genre_name) REFERENCES genre(name),
        FOREIGN KEY (tvshow_title) REFERENCES tvshow(title)
    );
"""
```

Comment: `where g.name='{genre}'`      - it should be in quotes

Comment: What is the purpose of the quotes around the variable when I'm using a f-string?

Comment: Print this string after making `genre = 'Action'`, you'll see that `Action` is without quotes

Comment: I don't know much about f-strings, the fact is that it doesn't set the quotes here.